# Grails 2 with non HTML5 scaffolding

Tags: html, grails, grails-2.0

I'm working on a Grails 2 app, which has HTML 5 based scaffolding. For non HTML 5 browsers, will the gsp tags generate non HTML 5 or can we not use Grails 2 in that case? Or is there a way to disable HTML 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 will be rendered no matter what.  Its not really Grails job to determine what to do in every browser.  You have a couple of options:

1. Use something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) so that your HTML5 will work in older
   browsers
2. [Install the Grails templates](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) and replace all the HTML5 with
   something else.

Obviously, #1 would be preferred.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought. Thanks.